# C Graphics Programming : Display X/Y Axis

Tags: graphics, turbo-c, dosbox

How to display the x and y axis in Turbo C for graphics programming. I mean is there a known code for it which I have to add in my program to display the axes?

Comment: The C standard does not know about graphics programming. Why can't you use a fancier GUI toolkit, maybe [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), -or [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/) and a better compiler [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: I have a practical exam tomorrow and we have to do it in Turbo C only.

Comment: Turbo C is more than 20 years old and you're not likely going to get much help with it. An exam is not practical if it relies on Turbo C.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by getting familiar with the [graphics functions](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_C/Graphics/Index.html) available in Turbo C and Turbo C++. For what you are trying to accomplish you will want to read up on [`outtextxy`](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_C/Graphics/outtextxy.html) which will allow you to draw text to the screen at a specific location. In C you can do something like this

```
char text[100];
int xPos = 6;
int yPos = 10;
sprintf(text, "X = %d, Y = %d", xPos, yPos);
outtextxy(0, 0, text);
```

This will display the values of `xPos` and `yPos` at the top left hand corner of the screen as `X = 6, Y = 10`.

See the example in the link to `outtextxy` for full details on which header files to include,  initializing the display, and other function calls that will come in handy.